# Angular translate race condition

Tags: angularjs, race-condition, angular-translate

I am running into a race condition using angular-translate-loader-partial.

First, I change the state of the loader using `$translatePartialLoader.addPart(partname)`, which requires the table to then be updated. [See API for details](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.%24translatePartialLoader)

Next, I call `$translate(translateKey)`. This begins a race. It may or may not display the translation, depending on whether or not the language file has been loaded yet.

How can I ensure that my partial files are all loaded before I use $translate?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to hook the $translatePartialLoaderStructureChanged event. Which will only be triggered once the part is avaialable.

To make sure that the part is avaialable:

```
        $rootScope.$on('$translatePartialLoaderStructureChanged', function (e, Part_Name) {
            if (Part_Name === 'PartThatYouNeed') {
                $translate.refresh().then(function () {
                    $translate(translateKey);
                });
            }
        });
```

Or perhaps a better option if this is to be used throughout your application, you can hook this event and call the refresh function in your applications run command like this

```
app.run(function ($state, $rootScope, $translate) {
        $rootScope.$on('$translatePartialLoaderStructureChanged', function (e, Part_Name) {
            $translate.refresh();
        });
});
```

And if you need to run setup code after the language table is accessible I would suggest a rootScope emit after the refresh is complete:

```
app.run(function ($state, $rootScope, $translate) {
    $rootScope.$on('$translatePartialLoaderStructureChanged', function (e, Part_Name) {
        $translate.refresh().then(function () {
            $rootScope.$emit('ApplicationTranslationsRefreshed', Part_Name);
        });
    });
});
```

After this anywhere in your app you can hook the ApplicationTranslationsRefreshed event to know when $translate('key_that_is_in_the_new_part') is useable:

```
        $rootScope.$on('ApplicationTranslationsRefreshed', function (e, Part_Name) {
            console.debug(Part_Name + "is now avaialable")
        });
```